# Windows 7 File Editing Permissions

Tags: windows, security, permissions

I have a program that creates a text log file daily. I want to be able to access the file and read the data in it, but I don't want anyone or any group to be able to delete or edit this file whatsoever.

Is there any way to enable this for this program only via permissions or any other way? This is a Windows 7 machine in a domain environment.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the folder permissions for the Builtin **System** User to **Write**  and or **Modify** and just set the **Builtin** **Everyone Group** to **Read**.
This presumes the application runs with some level of System privilege unless it actually has installed a user account, which you'd set that particular user with **Write** and or **Modify** perms.

Permissions are object access based, while system privileges are more well-defined system functions and a decent primer distinguishing both can be found at the Information Security sister site:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41309/difference-between-privilege-and-permission

Microsoft's albeit Windows 2000 quick sheet but relevant still of these perms are provided at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

[image]